# Apply CSS to button when form is invalid

Tags: css, angularjs

**HTML**

```
<div class="filterButt">
      <input type="hidden" name="reportParams">
      <span class="pull-right">
         <button type="submit" ng-disabled="!filter.$valid" ng-click='filterComponents()' data-toggle="modal" id="filterClose" class="btn-flat default" href="#myModal1"><i class="icon-ok-sign">Save</i></button>
      </span>
</div><!--#filterButt-->
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-flat {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 0 none;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #2b73b0;
  border: 1px solid #3883c0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 7px 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all .1s linear;
  -moz-transition: all .1s linear;
  transition: all .1s linear;
}
```

**Button Image**

[image]

I am using AngularJS here (everybody knows that :-)). Here I want to disable the save button when the form is not valid, I can able to do that but I also want to apply some other CSS like greying down the button etc when the form has validation errors.

I tried ng-class like below

```
ng-class="{btn-disable: !filter.$valid }"
```

But it didn't applied, Can anybody help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: please also show your javascript, especially the part with `filter.$valid`

Comment: Could you provide us a Plunker or a JsFiddle reproducing your issue ?

Comment: filter is just my form name, i am disabling the button here when the form is not valid

Comment: Yea, I'm not sure.  My answer was downvoted too.  @vamsi, did my answer by chance help you?

Comment: No bro, I tried your solution but no luck. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, the HTML block is missing the `form tag` so i dont know what your form class is.

So ill just use the `form` and `button` tag in scss:

```
form {
    &:valid {
        background-color: green;
        button[type="submit"] {
             background-color: lightgreen;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing

`ng-class="{btn-disable: !filter.$valid }"`

to

`ng-class="{'btn-disable': !filter.$valid }"`

Notice the single quotes.

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6NGFd/) for the difference (and be sure to look at the error in the JS console!)